# Subsetting a dataframe based on "negation"

Tags: r

What I am trying to do is basically create a subset of a data frame of patients who DO NOT have a specific diagnosis code.

For example, let’s say I do not want the code 1111,1112, and 1113 in the diagnosis NIS codes ( all patients BUT the ones that have this code)

I was thinking I would do something like this, but it is not working for me :(

Let’s say there is only 10 diagnosis codes in the NIS files (even though it usually goes up to 30)

`dataframe1<- subset(dataframe1, grepl(!1111,DX1) | grepl(!1111, DX2) | grepl(!1111, DX3) | grepl(!1111, DX4) | grepl(!1111, DX5) | grepl(!1111, DX6) | grepl(!1111, DX7) | grepl(!1111, DX8) | grepl(!1111, DX9) | grepl(!1111, DX10) | grepl(!1112,DX1) | grepl(!1112, DX2) | grepl(!1112, DX3) | grepl(!1112, DX4) | grepl(!1112, DX5) | grepl(!1112, DX6) | grepl(!1112, DX7) | grepl(!1112, DX8) | grepl(!1112, DX9) | grepl(!1112, DX10) | | grepl(!1113,DX1) | grepl(!1113, DX2) | grepl(!1113, DX3) | grepl(!1113, DX4) | grepl(!1113, DX5) | grepl(!1113, DX6) | grepl(!1113, DX7) | grepl(!1113, DX8) | grepl(!1113, DX9) | grepl(!1113, DX10))`

I used the “!” because I thought this meant “negate” or chose those that do NOT have this ID.

When I ran it, it gave me 0 observations- can someone help please?

I have also tried to do this `dataframe1<- filter(dataframe1, !(DX1:DX30 %in% 1111:1113))` and that gave me this message:

> "Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)"

Comment: The `!` should be outside i.e. `!grepl(1111, DX1)` and if it is a fixed match use `==` or `!=` or `%in%` with `!`.  Also, this may be easier with `library(dplyr);dataframe1 %>% filter(across(DX1:DX10, ~  ! . %in% c(1111, 1112, 1113)))`

Comment: The rows are patients and you want patients that have at least one value `DX*` not in `1111:1113`?

Comment: Hey @akrun - this is so so helpful- thank you- I used the second one and I received this message: Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
( I am using an NIS file so it has 7296968 obs out of 182 variables.) Do you happen to know what I can do about this? Sending you good wishes.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hi Rui! The rows are patients, yes, and I want all of the patients to NOT contain 1111:1113 in ANY of the DX* They should not have that code anywhere in any diagnoses.

Comment: If memory is an issue, probably do this on a fresh R session with `data.table`.  It is better to provide a small reproducible example with expected output so that we can test to help you better

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R way.

```
not_wanted <- 1111:1113
inx <- apply(dataframe1, 1, function(x) all(!x %in% not_wanted))
dataframe1[inx, ]
#   DX1  DX2  DX3  DX4
#9 1116 1115 1115 1116
```

**Note:** If performance is important, R matrix accesses are faster than data.frame accesses.
To coerce first

```
mat1 <- dataframe1
```

will double this code's speed.

---

### Test data

```
set.seed(2021)
dataframe1 <- replicate(4, sample(1111:1116, 20, TRUE))
dataframe1 <- as.data.frame(dataframe1)
names(dataframe1) <- paste0("DX", 1:4)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, you can use `if_any` in `filter` -

```
values <- c(1111, 1112, 1113)
res <- dataframe1 %>% filter(!if_any(DX1:DX30, ~. %in% values))
```

In base R, here are two options with `sapply`/`lapply` -

```
cols <- grep('DX', names(dataframe1))
#1. lapply
res <- dataframe1[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(dataframe1[cols], `%in%`, values)), ]

#2. sapply
res <- dataframe1[rowSums(sapply(dataframe1[cols], `%in%`, values)) == 0,]
```